Prove a continuous bijection between the space of probability distributions is a homeomorphism
Let $\Delta([\underline p, \overline p])$ denote the set of all cumulative distribution functions (CDF) supported on the compact set $[\underline p, \overline p]$. $G_i\in \Delta([\underline p_i, \overline p_i])$ is one CDF and $G=\prod_{i=1}^I G_i\in \prod_{i=1}^I \Delta([\underline p_i, \overline p_i])$ is a collection of $I$ CDFs where $I$ is finite.
Function $f\in C^1\colon \prod_i [\underline p_i, \overline p_i]\to \Delta^0_I$ where $\Delta^0_I$ is the interior of $I$-dimensional simplex. Function $f$ and $G$ determine a collection of $I$ functions $E_1$, $E_2$,...,$E_I$
$$E_i(p_i;G)=\int_{p_{-i}}f_i(p_i, p_{-i})\prod_{k,k\neq i}dG_k(p_k)$$
where $f_i$ is the i-th entry of the output of $f$, and $p_{-i}=(p_1, \cdots, p_{i-1}, p_{i+1}, \cdots, p_I)$. Another collection of $I$ CDF $\tilde G=\prod_{i=1}^I \tilde G_i\in \prod_{i=1}^I \Delta([\underline p_i, \overline p_i])$ is given by
$$\tilde G_i(p)=\frac{\int_{\underline p_i}^p  E_i(y;G)\times dG_i(y)}{\int_{\underline p_i}^{\overline p_i}  E_i(y;G)\times dG_i(y)}$$
The derivation above takes in $G$ and output $\tilde G$ (note $G$ and $\tilde G$ have the same support). Summarize this mapping from $G$ to $\tilde G$ by $T: \prod_{i=1}^I \Delta([\underline p_i, \overline p_i])\to \prod_{i=1}^I \Delta([\underline p_i, \overline p_i])$. Assume $T$ is a bijection. $T$ is also continuous by the two equations above. I want to show $T$ is a homeomorphism, i.e., $T^{-1}$ is continuous.
I tried some directions but I am missing pieces. The open mapping theorem does not work since the mapping ($G\to \tilde G$) is not linear. It is componentwise linear, i.e., fixing $G_{-i}$, the mapping from $G_{i}\to \tilde G$ is linear, ignoring the normalizing denominator. I tried induction on the number $I$ but failed ($I=1$ works trivally). Another related result is that a continuous bijection from a compact space to a Hausdorff space is a homeomorphism. But the space of G, the space of all probability distributions is not compact. Instead of all CDFs on the compact support, if we only focus on discrete probability mass distributions with fixed finite support, we do have a homoemorphism. I tried arguments like discretezation and passing on to the limit but also failed:(
